# axios is adding 52 to the middle of my string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get random words from the randomWords endpoint at this api

https://developer.wordnik.com/docs#!/words/getRandomWords

Here's my code:

```
const getWords = () => {
    let partsStr = '';
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(partsOfSpeech)) {
        if (value === true) {
            partsStr += `${key.toString()}%2C`;
        }
    }
    console.log(partsStr);
    axios.get(
        'https://api.wordnik.com/v4/words.json/randomWords?hasDictionaryDef=true',
        {
            params: {
                includePartofSpeech: partsStr.slice(0, -3),
                limit: limit,
                minLength: minLength,
                maxLength: maxLength,
                api_key: apiKey
            }
        }
    );
};

getWords();
```

when I `console.log(partsStr)` I get "noun%2Cverb%2Cadjective%2C"

But my string is showing up like this in the browser

https://api.wordnik.com/v4/words.json/randomWords?hasDictionaryDef=true&includePartofSpeech=noun%252Cverb%252Cadjective&limit=10&minLength=&maxLength=&api_key=key

so where is includePartofSpeech=noun%2**52**Cverb%2**52**Cadjective coming from?

Comment: why u add %2C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axios encodes your parameters automatically so your `%` in `%2C`is encoded to `%25` then you get `%252C`.
Do not manually encode the `,` to `%2C` leave it as a comma.

```
partsStr += `${key.toString()},`;
```

Comment: that's what I tried initially, but it sends the request with actual commas instead of encoding them

Comment: It seems Axios doesn't think comma should be encoded, not sure how to get around that. Does the comma really need to be encoded though?